# How to post NSDictionary to Django server

Tags: python, ios, objective-c, django

I’d like to send an NSDictionary to my Django server as the request.POST data.  I’ve tried a number of things, and looked at similar questions here, but none of them are working.  Here’s what I have on the client side:

```
NSString *url = @"http://mycompany.com/myurl";
NSDictionary *testDict = @{@"key1": @"value1", @"key2": @"value2"};
NSError *error;
if ([connectionController testPost:url dictionary:testDict returningResponse:&response error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Success!");
}
```

The `connectionController` object has this method:

```
- (BOOL)testPost:(NSString *)url dictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict returningResponse:(NSDictionary **)response error:(NSError **)error {
    NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:error];
    if (!data) {
        return NO;
    }
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:data];
    NSURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;
    NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:error];
    if (*error) {
        return NO;
    }
    *response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:error];
    return YES;
}
```

And on my Django server side:

```
def myurl_view_func(request):
    print "request = %s" % request
    key1 = request.POST.get('key1', None)
    print "key1 = %s" % key1
```

But when executed, the server doesn’t receive the NSDictionary.  Instead it prints:

```
request = <WSGIRequest
path:/myurl/,
GET:<QueryDict: {}>,
POST:<QueryDict: {}>,
...[snip]...

key1 = None
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daniel Roseman’s answer got me halfway there: looking in `request.body` not `request.POST`.  The rest was decoding `request.body` properly, as a JSON serialized dictionary.

Basically, the client as described above is fine.  You just need to change the server as follows:

```
from django.utils import simplejson

def myurl_view_func(request):
    data = simplejson.loads(request.body)
    key1 = data.get('key1', None)
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know anything about Objective-C, but if you're serializing the dictionary and posting it as JSON then the raw data will be found in `request.body`, not `request.POST`.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel, that was half of what I needed.  (See below.)  Thanks much!